# Header isn't centered but rest of the page is

Tags: html, css

Been trying to figure out for a couple of days now why the logo in the header which you can see here: https://gyazo.com/5eb973585ce428f9d34bc7bd46aec14c isn't centered with the rest of the page like with the arrow below it in the picture.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'cabinregular';
  src: url('font1/cabin-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('font1/cabin-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open_sansregular';
  src: url(font2/opensans-regular-webfont.woff2) format("woff2"), url(font2/opensans-regular-webfont.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'edoregular';
  src: url(font3/edo-webfont.woff2) format("woff2"), url(font3/edo-webfont.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 16px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 16px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 16px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.headeritems {
  text-align: center;
}
.navigationleft {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigationleft ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigationleft li {
  display: inline;
}
.navigationleft li a {
  color: #BEBEBE;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 24px 40px 0px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: cabinregular;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: color .20s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color .20s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color .20s ease-in-out;
}
.navigationleft li a:hover {
  color: #00C4FF;
}
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.navigationright {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigationright ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigationright li {
  display: inline;
}
.navigationright li a {
  color: #BEBEBE;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 24px 40px 0px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: cabinregular;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: color .20s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color .20s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color .20s ease-in-out;
}
.navigationright li a:hover {
  color: #00C4FF;
}
.container {
  background-image: url(images/container.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: cover;
  height: 650px;
}
.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 650px;
  padding-top: 250px;
  color: white;
  font-family: edoregular;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-shadow: 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.arrow1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60px;
  margin-top: 170px;
  transition: padding-top .20s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: padding-top .20s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: padding-top .20s ease-in-out;
}
.arrow1:hover {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.contentabout {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 650px;
  height: 550px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-family: edoregular;
  text-align: justify;
}
.contentabout h1 {
  height: 50px;
  color: #2D2D2D;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
.contentabout p {
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-family: open_sansregular;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.arrow2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60px;
  margin-top: 145px;
  transition: padding-top .20s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: padding-top .20s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: padding-top .20s ease-in-out;
}
.arrow2:hover {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.containerportfolio {
  height: 720px;
  background-image: url(images/containerportfolio.jpg);
}
.contentportfolio {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 709px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  font-family: edoregular;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.contentportfolio h1 {
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.portfolioitems {
  height: 400px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.portfolioitems p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: open_sansregular;
  font-size 30px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.byggfram {
  width: 220px;
  height: 124px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 56px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 56px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 56px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transition: opacity .20s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .20s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .20s ease-in-out;
}
.byggfram:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.classie {
  width: 220px;
  height: 124px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 56px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 56px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 56px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transition: opacity .20s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .20s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .20s ease-in-out;
}
.classie:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.anderssonsvensson {
  width: 220px;
  height: 124px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 56px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 56px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 56px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transition: opacity .20s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .20s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .20s ease-in-out;
}
.anderssonsvensson:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.arrow3 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60px;
  margin-top: 85px;
  transition: padding-top .20s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: padding-top .20s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: padding-top .20s ease-in-out;
}
.arrow3:hover {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.containercontact {
  height: 650px;
}
.contact {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 650px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.titlecontact {
  text-align: center;
}
.contact h1 {
  font-family: edoregular;
  color: #2D2D2D;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>Loom | Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="home" name="home"></a>
  <a id="home" name="top"></a>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="headeritems">
      <div class="navigationleft">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#home">
          <img src="css/images/loomlogo.svg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="navigationright">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#portfolio" class="smoothScroll">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      Loom Is Lemon
      <div class="arrow1">
        <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">
          <img src="css/images/arrowdown.svg" style="width:60px">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a id="about" name="about"></a>
  <div class="containerabout">
    <div class="contentabout">
      <h1>Greetings from Sweden!</h1>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <div class="arrow2">
        <a href="#portfolio" class="smoothScroll">
          <img src="css/images/arrowdown2.svg" style="width:60px">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a id="portfolio" name="portfolio"></a>
  <div class="containerportfolio">
    <div class="contentportfolio">
      <h1>Portfolio</h1>
      <div class="portfolioitems">
        <div class="byggfram">
          <img src="css/images/byggfram.png">
        </div>
        <div class="classie">
          <img src="css/images/classie.png">
        </div>
        <div class="anderssonsvensson">
          <img src="css/images/anderssonsvensson.png">
        </div>
        <p>More coming soon!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="arrow3">
        <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">
          <img src="css/images/arrowdown.svg" style="width:60px">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="containercontact">
    <div class="contact">
      <div class="titlecontact">
        <img src="css/images/loomlogo2.svg">
        <h1>Contact Me!</h1>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/smoothscroll.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You're centering three elements: `.navigationleft`, `.logo`and `.navigationright`. They are centered as a group, however the left and right elements are different sizes, so the `logo` doesn't appear in the exact middle. You have too much CSS there for me to look through it and correct it, but if you force each menu link to be the same width, your logo will be central.

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right, thanks man

Answer (score -1):

You could try putting:

```
<center></center>
```

around the part that isn't centered.

Comment: The center element has been depreciated since HTML4, and is generally a nasty solution.

Comment: that's true but it has solved my problem multiple times.